# "To out" meaning

Tags: verbs

In Harry Potter and the prisoner of Azkaban I came across a sentence:

- Bad blood will **out**.

> The context is this: Aunt Marge while sitting at the table is talking about Harry's parents who she thinks have bad blood. She is saying that eventually a sibling of such parents won't be any better and bad blood runs in Harry's veins either.

I understand that "**out**" here is a verb and I understand by the context what it can mean. I would like to know - if we were to use a different verb or phrase then what would it be?

I'm thinking of "**reveal itself**" or "**stand out**". What other options are there?

P.s. is this verb "**to out**" common?

Comment: You really need to give a sentence in which you provide the subject of this verb you're seeking. Or is "bad blood" the subject?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The sentence is as is and I quoted it straightforward.

Comment: I mean, do you want to say "Bad blood _______?" or are you looking for a *general-purpose* synonym for the intransitive verb **out**, which can be used with things other than bad blood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"X will out"* is an idiomatic expression, that means (as you guessed) that some distinctive *negative* quality in a family will reveal itself (in the children) in time.

As far as I know it's only used for negative (presumably hereditary) qualities, and not positive qualities.  For those there are different expressions:

> She has a **noble lineage**.
>
> Hard work and tenacity are **in her blood**.
>
> Creativity **runs in her family**.

and others.  Although the last two can also be negative.

> Her parents were criminals, and, mark my words, she'll be one too.  Larceny **runs in her family**.

Comment: I don't know that it's negative, so much as it is referring to something someone is hiding, which tends to be negative. The phrase I think it comes from is ["the truth will out"](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/390200.html).

Comment: @ColleenV  good point, I knew there was another variation that I couldn't recall.  Although even "the truth will out" has a negative context, that someone has *deliberately hidden* the truth.  I can't think of a case where "X will out" suggests an as-of-yet unseen positive quality that will reveal itself in time, can you?

Comment: The truth isn’t a positive or negative thing in and of itself unless you’re the one lying ;) You’re correct though that the truth that will out is generally unpleasant.

Comment: @ColleenV Don't forget "Murder will out" a very common if now old-fashioned phrase.  That is not at all a hereditary quality, although it is one both hidden and negative.

Answer (score 1):

out (v.)

Old English: utian "expel, put out"; used in many senses over the years.

[... (modern meanings of the verb, "out")]

sense of "disclose to public view, reveal, make known" has been present since mid-14c.

Example: "Eufrosyne preyde Þat god schulde not outen hire to nowiht." [Legendary of St. Euphrosyne, c. 1350]

Related: Outed; outing.

https://www.etymonline.com/word/out